# ThreadAbortException on SPWeb.ProcessBatchData

Tags: splistitem, spweb, exception, batch

I am trying to update ~2000 list items with SPWeb.ProcessBatchData.
After exception on all items at a time, I tried them in small batches like 100 and 200 but after executing first 1 or 2 batches i.e. after updating ~400 list items following exception occurs.

```
System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Thread was being aborted.
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.ProcessBatchData(String bstrUrl, String bstrData, ISPDataCallback pResultCallback)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.ProcessBatchData(String bstrUrl, String bstrData, ISPDataCallback pResultCallback)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.ProcessBatchData(String strBatchData)
```

Following is the code i used to update list items:

```
            var list = web.Lists["ListName"];
            var listGuid = list.ID;

            for (int i = 0; i < clients.Count; i++)
            {
                StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();
                for (int j = 0; j < 100 && i < items.Count; j++, i++)
                {
                    var client = items[i];
                    query.AppendFormat("<Method ID=\"{0}\">" +
                            "<SetList>{1}</SetList>" +
                            "<SetVar Name=\"ID\">{4}</SetVar>" +
                            "<SetVar Name=\"Cmd\">Save</SetVar>" +
                            "<SetVar Name=\"{3}{5}\">{2}</SetVar>" +
                         "</Method>", i + 1, listGuid, DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ"), "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office#"
                         , client.ID, DateFieldName);
                }

                var t = string.Format("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><ows:Batch OnError=\"Return\">" +
                                      "{0}</ows:Batch>", query);

                var result = web.ProcessBatchData(t);                
                i--;
            }
```

Do anyone know why this exception is coming? What is the solution for it? Your help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: in your web.config what values are defined here? <httpRuntime  executionTimeout="??" maxRequestLength="??" />

Comment: @Gwny <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="51200" requestValidationMode="2.0" executionTimeout="200" />

Comment: and how long does it take? maybe the execution Timeout is your problem?

Comment: It is taking ~100 seconds for 100 records. Is it the ideal time for updating 100 items?

Answer (score 0):

The executionTimeout in web.config specifies the maximum number of seconds that a request is allowed to execute before being automatically shut down by ASP.NET.

Try setting it to at least 2000 seconds for your 2000 Items.

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="51200" requestValidationMode="2.0" executionTimeout="2000" />
```